# Determinant Problem

Tags: determinant

**Question:**

[image: Problem]

My problem:

I can't understand how does the hint work.I also want to know the best method to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried just flat-out computing the determinant and using some trig identities?

Comment: i would use this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus

Comment: @Mathematician42 I was confused by seeing cos x in the rows.

Comment: I can do the determination.I was having problem by the row operation provided in the steps.And don't make fun of others.Everyone starts from scratch .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Laplace expansion formula for the first line (which is a property of determinants) to obtain:

$$\det \boldsymbol{A}=a(-a^2-1)-\sin x \left[-a\sin x -\cos x \right]+\cos x\left[-\sin x + a\cos x \right]$$
$$=-a^3-a+a\sin^2 x +\sin x \cos x- \sin x \cos x+a\cos^2 x$$
$$=-a^3-a+a(\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x)=-a^3-a+a\cdot 1=-a^3.$$

**Edit for row operations**:

If $R_1 = \begin{bmatrix} a & \sin x & \cos x\end{bmatrix}$ and $R_3 = \begin{bmatrix} \cos x & 1 & a\end{bmatrix}$ then
$$-\sin x R_3= \begin{bmatrix} -\sin x\cos x & -\sin x & -a\sin x\end{bmatrix}$$

hence, if we add $-\sin x R_3$ to the first row $R_1$ we obtain:

$$R_1 -\sin xR_3=\begin{bmatrix} a-\sin x\cos x & 0 & \cos x-a\sin x\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then you obtain the new first row.

Comment: Can you provide the row operations by editing your answer.

Comment: I am having problem with the row operation.

Comment: Added more details. But to be honest. Doing row operations is not a good idea for such a simple problem.

Comment: Actually this is in our class 12 syllabus.And I have no option rather than to follow this method.If I try any other method I would not given proper marks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in the hint which should be $R_1-\sin x \cdot R_3$ and $R_2+a\cdot R_3$ (the first of these has $R_2$ in the text). This may explain your confusion. And the result is wrong even then - the hint has two significant errors.

The strategy being used is to use elementary row operations to make most of the second column zero, then to expand the determinant using the second column, because most of the components are zero.

Here it seems as easy just to expand the determinant using the first row.

Comment: I have edited this, because working through the hint shows that it has more than one significant flaw.

Comment: Thanks .You are very helpful.There are some people who constantly comment nonsense and disturb the good flow of the community.I hope you continue your good work.

Answer (score 2):

by the rule of Sarrus we get$$-a^3+\sin(x)\cos(x)-\cos(x)\sin(x)+a^2\sin^2(x)-a+a\cos^2(x)$$

Comment: OK thanks for your answer.